# Image inside anchor tag in Boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, i experienced one thing about img inside anchor tag.

1) If you inspect the anchor tag it will have height greater than img. I found the answer because img has display block css.

2) Then also I dont know why it took max height than img?  then if i put display block to both a tag and img tag then problem solved(both height equals).

Now coming back to point 1) suppose if I remove display block from img then anchor tag will have height equals to 16px why is that?

then if u remove browser styles like bootstrap font-size and default font-size and line height then the anchor tag height moves to 19px height. 
Why?

Comment: I think some has to do with you're wrapping the img with an ``a`` tag.  Is this a simple curiosity question or is it effecting the functionality of your page?

Comment: just a curiosity question

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any styles, the `<a>` is an inline element, and there's nothing in it that makes it grow larger than its standard height (the computed line-height of the font in effect), even if you put an `<img>` in there that's larger.
So, when the font-size is 16px and the line-height is 1.2, you have a 19 pixel high `<a>`.

However, if you change the display type of the the `<img>` to `block`, the `<a>` is no longer a simple inline element. With block content, it effectively becomes a block itself, and then it takes on the height of its content. (That's what block elements do.)

As to the sizes with Bootstrap in effect; yes, the Bootstrap css sets the font size to 14px, so the height will be 16px.

Comment: ok but if i remove all styling including browser styles it leads to 19px only .. thats my question

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain than I did in the first paragraph. Without any styles, what would you expect?